# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know why i have this error!!
At first time i dont have any error and its work But when i refresh the page i have this error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined** or **TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined**

```
import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
import Content from './Content';
import NavBar from './NavBar';

    export default function BlogPost() {

    const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
       const cleanUp = fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts')
       .then( response => response.json())
       .then( post => 
           setPost(post),
           setCurrent(0)
       )
       return () => cleanUp;
    },[])

    function handleClick(index) {
        setCurrent(index)
    }
     

    return (
        <div className="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
          <NavBar posts={post} handleClick={handleClick} />
          { null != current && <Content post={post[current]} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Content.jsx :

```
export default function Content({post}) {
    return (
       <div>
          <div id="content" className="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
        <img src={`/assets/${post.image}`} alt={post.title} />
     <h2 className="mb-4">{post.title}</h2>
     <p>{post.body}</p>
  </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<h2 className="mb-4">{post.title}</h2>
```

here `post` object will get data from axios call and it will take some time to fetch the data that means on initial render `title` will not be there. So you have to put some check and access that key only when it is available.

Try something like:

```
<h2 className="mb-4">{post && post.title}</h2>
```

Or you can also try `conditional rendering`

Answer (score 0):

you could do the below instead:

```
export default function Content({post}) {
    return post ? (
       <div>
         <div id="content" className="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
           <img src={`/assets/${post.image}`} alt={post.title} />
           <h2 className="mb-4">{post.title}</h2>
           <p>{post.body}</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    ) : null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help And explanation